# unity3d version 5.6.2f1 personal cannot open Learn Tab

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

unity3d version 5.6.2f1 personal cannot open Learn Tab upon failure to download a tutorial (shooting tutorial, not the space shooter) from disconnection to internet, always stuck on project tab.

[image: screenshot for the unity home screen]

I keep on clicking after loading still it cannot open, tried reinstalling unity still the same.

below is screenshot for when open in web:

[image: Learn Tab open in web]